# Do I need 2 virtual hosts for both www.example.com and just example.com?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, apache2

I have 2 questions - does it matter if the ServerName in Apache's conf file starts with www? Also if I have the following virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Should I also have the following one:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Apache [`ServerName`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#servername) directive is used in among others the default (error) messages and headers that Apache generates. Some people prefer to have those match the hostname a site visitor used.

Then you need a VirtualHost for each and every URL hostname.

Other people prefer fewer VirtualHost blocks and use the [`ServerAlias`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#serveralias) directive to assign alternate names to a virtual host (when the same content can be used for all names).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com example.net www.example.net
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Which name you use for the ServerName is as far as I know mostly a matter of preference. Some prefer the bare domain, others the www record.

And, as @HåkanLindqvist commented, you can also decide on a single URI to publish your website and redirect your other domains to that site:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
    ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect "/" "http://www.example.com"
</VirtualHost>
```

(Where it should be noted that you should set up a TLS certificate and use and redirect to HTTPS for your sites.)

Comment: This answers the question as asked, but one consideration that might be worth mentioning is that it's usually good practice to decide on one canonical name and redirect any aliases to that one name, rather than actually serving the same content/services via multiple names.